# Bootstrap 5 + Masonry + Fancybox gallery getting destroyed when uploaded to hosting

Tags: layout, fancybox, bootstrap-5, masonry, lightgallery

I have a problem with using Bootstrap plus Masonry for my layout. Trying it out on my computer, it works perfectly, but when I upload it to GitHub pages or Godaddy hosting, it sometimes gets destroyed like the image I shared. I bought Lightgallery and tried it instead of Fancybox to make the photo gallery, just in case something there was making a problem, but it's the same.

The problem being Masonry or bootstrap, I can't get rid of bootstrap but could use an alternative to Masonry. My client just needs the Pinterest-like layout.

It's very frustrating because it works perfectly until it is live. I tried a lot of things but nothing has worked. Thank you for any idea you could give me, and sorry for my bad English.

Github link: https://m-ribero.github.io/mubles-ballena/galeria.html

edit: Very important detail, it often gets fixed after reloading or resizing the page, but for the first time someone enters there, then it doesn't motivate people to invest more time in the site if it looks that bad.

[gallery destroyed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA4VE.jpg)

[gallery destroyed 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBJZp.jpg)

Comment: Hello, I think you could get a lot of useful information opening it with a developer console and maybe adding in info on the possible asset loading errors? It could give you a good tip on what the problem is. Or maybe even posting an url for someone to take a look?
It could be a number of things that are causing this behavior.
Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Lourenzo. Here I have a github link: https://m-ribero.github.io/mubles-ballena/galeria.html

As far as I could look, there doesn't seem to appear any loading errors, it sometimes just loads wrong and I can't see any difference or error compared to when it works as intended. In mobile it even gets destroyed more often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with Masonry and not Fancybox (or any other lightbox alternative). Looks like it incorrectly calculates height for the container. Since it works after assets have been cached, I guess that your masonry script does all calculations before your CSS is loaded. Therefore top/bottom padding is not taken into account for calculations.

Comment: That seems to be the case. Do you have any advice on how I make sure my CSS is loaded before Masonry? I've been trying a few things out (disable a spinner that it had, make the padding gutters from bootstrap instead, using no padding or margin at all), but couldn't fix it. Thanks a lot Janis!

Comment: I do not know what exactly to suggest, but it seems to be working fine for you.

Comment: For everyone who wants to know what I did after.

With an onload event in body I now call a function that wraps all masonry code and put a delay of 1.5 seconds to trigger it. It seems to be working perfectly now, but the last items get over the footer sometimes. But it's just a detail that makes no difference compared to what I had before. Thanks again!